# How do I change the size of the Flet window on Windows or specify that it is not resizable?

Tags: python, flutter, window, resize, window-resize

In Flet on Windows, I'm running the calc demo and trying to modify properties of the application window in Python.

How do I change the size of the Flet window in code and specify that it should not be user resizable?

(Ideally this post should be tagged with 'Flet' but the tag doesn't exist yet as the project's in it's infancy and I don't have the 1500 points required to created it.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no specific code to add!?  Flet is a new project to implement Flutter functionality in Python cross-platform.  I want to know how to resize the window programmatically.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this as an example

```
import flet as ft

def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.window_width = 200        # window's width is 200 px
    page.window_height = 200       # window's height is 200 px
    page.window_resizable = False  # window is not resizable
    page.update()


ft.app(target=main)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

To set the window's size and resizable:

```
def main(page: Page):
page.window_width = 200        # window's width is 200 px
page.window_height = 200       # window's height is 200 px
page.window_resizable = False  # window is not resizable
```

The [flet docs](https://flet.dev/docs/) is very nice and easy to read.
Please read the [Page](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/page) docs to learn more about "page".